# Unable to connect to L2TP VPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn

I've been trying to set up a L2TP/IPSec server on my Ubuntu install using [this guide](http://www.slsmk.com/setup-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu/).

While trying to connect I ran `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log`, the output of which is below:

```
Feb  8 10:35:41 prometheus pluto[6167]: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[20] [my ip] #20: responding to Main Mode from unknown peer [my ip]
Feb  8 10:35:41 prometheus pluto[6167]: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[20] [my ip] #20: Can't authenticate: no preshared key found for `[server ip]' and `%any'.  Attribute OAKLEY_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD
Feb  8 10:35:41  pluto[6167]: last message repeated 5 times
Feb  8 10:35:41 prometheus pluto[6167]: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[20] [my ip] #20: no acceptable Oakley Transform
Feb  8 10:35:41 prometheus pluto[6167]: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[20] [my ip] #20: sending notification NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN to [my ip]:500
Feb  8 10:35:41 prometheus pluto[6167]: "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"[20] [my ip]: deleting connection "L2TP-PSK-noNAT" instance with peer [my ip] {isakmp=#0/ipsec=#0}
```

---

### /etc/ipsec.conf

```
version 2.0

config setup
  dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
  nat_traversal=yes
  virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
  oe=off
  protostack=netkey
  keep_alive=10

include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

### /etc/ipsec.d/road-warrior.conf

```
conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
authby=secret
  pfs=no
  auto=add
  keyingtries=3
  rekey=no
  ikelifetime=8h
  keylife=1h
  type=transport
  left=[server ip]
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  right=%any
  rightprotoport=17/%any

conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
  rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
  also=L2TP-PSK-noNAT
```

### /etc/ipsec.d/road-warrior.secrets

```
[server ip] %any: PSK "psk"
```

### Output of `ipsec verify`

```
Version check and ipsec on-path                                 [OK]
Linux Openswan U2.6.37/K3.12.9-x86_64-linode37 (netkey)
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [OK]
 SAref kernel support                                           [N/A]
 NETKEY:  Testing XFRM related proc values                      [OK]
    [OK]
    [OK]
Checking that pluto is running                                  [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                             [OK]
 Pluto listening for NAT-T on udp 4500                          [OK]
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding            [OK]
Checking NAT and MASQUERADEing                                  [OK]
Checking for 'ip' command                                       [OK]
Checking /bin/sh is not /bin/dash                               [WARNING]
Checking for 'iptables' command                                 [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]
```

### /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf

```
[global]
ipsec saref = yes

[lns default]
ip range = 10.10.10.2-10.10.10.200  
local ip = 10.10.10.1
refuse chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

### /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd

```
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 4.2.2.1
ms-dns 4.2.2.2
asyncmap 0
auth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
debug
name l2tpd
proxyarp
lcp-echo-interval 30
lcp-echo-failure 4
```

### /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
user1           l2tpd   user1password           *
user2           l2tpd   user2password           *
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Because the error line says:

`Can't authenticate: no preshared key found for [server ip]' and %any'`.

This leads me to believe that it is possible your /etc/ipsec.d/road-warrior.secrets
file has a [serverip] that does not match the same as ipsec.conf `left=[serverip]`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it turned out that I had to restart the ipsec service (reloading the configuration did not suffice).

Only then did the service recognize the new PSK in ipsec.config.